# In MATLAB how do I insert a string at beginning of of each string in a cell array?

Tags: string, matlab, insert, string-concatenation, cell-array

I have a cell array of numeric strings e.g.:

```
labels = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'}
```

I'm trying to add a string (`'Label '`) to the beginning of each array element without using any kind of loop, as the array is massive and I need the code to run quickly. My other requirement is the space after the word `'Label'` must be maintained once I apply it to the two-digit elements in the array. The result I want is:

```
fullLabels = {'Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3', 'Label 4', 'Label 5',
              'Label 6', 'Label 7', 'Label 8', 'Label 9', 'Label 10',
              'Label 11', 'Label 12'}
```

I tried using [`strcat()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) like this:

```
fullLabels = strcat('Label ', labels);
```

This is fine for the single-digit array elements, but when it is applied to the two-digit array elements, the space after `'Label'` is removed to give:

```
fullLabels = {..., 'Label10', 'Label11', 'Label12'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat` trims trailing whitespace from all inputs prior to concatenation. You will want to manually concatenate the strings using `[]`.

```
fullLabels = cellfun(@(x)['Label ', x], labels, 'UniformOutput', false)

%   'Label 1'
%   'Label 2'
%   'Label 3'
%   'Label 4'
%   'Label 5'
%   'Label 6'
%   'Label 7'
%   'Label 8'
%   'Label 9'
%   'Label 10'
%   'Label 11'
%   'Label 12'
```

You could also use something like `regexprep` to prepend the label. This replaces the first character of each label with itself (`\1`) with `'Label '` appended to the front.

```
fullLabels = regexprep(labels, '^.', 'Label \1')
```

**Update**

@Dev-iL's answer mentioned using a cell array to pass a space to `strcat` which I wasn't aware of. Rather than concatenating the space, we could also just stick `'Label '` *inside* the cell.

```
strcat({'Label '}, labels)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Suever. I will try both with my data and go with the quickest. I suspect the time difference will be negligible anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since `strcat` only removes *trailing* spaces, if you manage to get your number strings to begin with a space (using the settings of whatever converts them from "proper numbers"), you will not see this problem:

```
labels = {' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9', ' 10', ' 11', ' 12'};
fullLabels = strcat('Label',labels);
```

Alternatively, as mentioned [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255105#661919), you can "fool" `strcat` by surrounding the space with a cell:

```
fullLabels = strcat('Label', {' '}, labels);
```

Comment: I would say the first part of this answer is not really complete, as it does not suggest a way to get the spaces in place. But I think the second option is the most readable solution.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - about the 1st solution: there are various ways to convert a vector of numbers into a cell array of strings having whichever format you need (chiefly `sprintf` and `num2str`), but as this is not the focus of the question, I only pointed it out as a possibility (to be used when applicable, of course).

Comment: @Dev-iL Didn't know you could do that (+1). Building off that, I posted an update to my answer which just uses `{'Label '}` as the first input. Clever.