# Why is strcat(mystring) different from mystring?

Tags: matlab

Doing

```
[~, currenthost] = system('hostname');
table({currenthost}, 'VariableNames', {'host'})
```

gives

```
ans = 

       host   
    __________

    [1x9 char]
```

while doing

```
[~, currenthost] = system('hostname');
table({strcat(currenthost)}, 'VariableNames', {'host'})
```

gives

```
ans = 

       host   
    _________

    'my-hostt'
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual difference is less than what you think.

`strcat` removes trailing spaces. Your `currenthost` variable is `'my-hosttt '` (note the last space). When you call `strcat` that last space is removed.

Coincidentally, MATLAB limit to display characters in tables is 9, so if there is a string of length 8, it will display the string itself, if its longer, it will just tell you the length of it!

Long story short: they are the same *type*, with a character less. MATLAB just displays them differently due to length.

Comment: Yep, that was it. How is one supposed to notice trailing spaces in Matlab command line though?!

Comment: @jakub yeah... you just had the bad luck that your hostname is 8 characters. If it were 9, you'd realize 1x9 and 1x10 char arrays!

Comment: @jakub take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37998621/3372061) for a trick to keep spaces when using `strcat`.

Comment: @Dev-iL nice :) In this case, I want the space removed actually. I don't know why, but when I call `[a, name] = system('hostname')`, the name clearly has x characters but length x + 1 - i.e. there is an extra space added. It is rather annoying, but easy to remove.